# a macro to choose the object instantiation based on the amount of the arguments

Tags: c++, macros

I'm trying to create a macro to choose the object instantiation based on the amount of the arguments. Macro must support zero to two arguments.
The desired result is selecting one of the following three, and pass 0 to 2 arguments if any:

```
    MyClass obj(hardcoded_arg); // Choose this one if no arguments passed to a macro
    MyClass obj(hardcoded_arg,arg1); // This one if a single argument passed
    MyClass obj(arg1,arg2); // This one if two arguments passed
```

Here is how I'm trying to achieve that:

```
    #define TYPE1(...)       MyClass obj(hardcoded_arg);
    #define TYPE2(arg1)      MyClass obj(hardcoded_arg,arg1);
    #define TYPE3(arg1,arg2) MyClass obj(arg1,arg2);

    #define EXPAND( x ) x
    #define GET_TYPE(DUMMY, _1 ,_2, NAME, ...) NAME
    #define INSTANTIATE(...) EXPAND(GET_TYPE(DUMMY ,##__VA_ARGS__, TYPE3, TYPE2, TYPE1))(__VA_ARGS__)

    INSTANTIATE()
    INSTANTIATE(1)
    INSTANTIATE(1,2)
```

I've tried using using a definition like

```
    #define VA_ARGS(...) , ##__VA_ARGS__ 
    #define INSTANTIATE(...) EXPAND(GET_TYPE(DUMMY VA_ARGS(__VA_ARGS__), TYPE3, TYPE2, TYPE1))(__VA_ARGS__)
```

but it also didn't resolve the case.
The solutions like INSTANTIATE(,) are lame.

Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: I dont understand why you need a macro at all. Why not just three constructors taking 0,1 or 2 parameters, respectively?

Comment: Because the hardcoded_arg is a "this" pointer of a calling object

Comment: then why dont you explicitly pass the pointer? Wouldnt that make the code easier to understand?

Comment: Yes, that is what the current code looks like. The MyClass behavior also depends on whether the calling method is const or not, so I was just trying to shorten the syntax with a macro. So now I'm just curious if such macro is possible at all.

Answer (score 1):

How about overloaded factory functions? Like

```
MyClass create() { return MyClass(hardecoded_arg); }
MyClass create(type2 arg2) { return MyClass(hardcoded_arg, arg2); }
MyClass create(type1 arg1, type2 arg2) { return MyClass(arg1, arg2); }
```

Type-safe, and no need to play tricks with the preprocessor.

Comment: Thank you for the answer dude! I forgot to say that the code is critical to the execution time and the idea is to make the code super fast.

Comment: The MyClass instance is forbidden to be copied

Comment: @user3348108 And have you measured that copying (which will most likely be [elided](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) anyway in this simple case) is so harmful to your program? How about movement then? And a general tip: Don't do premature optimizations. First of all make your program readable and maintainable. Then measure and benchmark and profile your program. When (and *if*) you find bottlenecks, then carefully tune them.

Comment: MyClass is an advanced thread-safety arbiter for a virtual file system (and that is why it can't be copied), so it is being instantiated really a lot. And that is why I am trying to place them on stack. Maybe the autopointers will make the stuff convenient then. Could you please explain your vision on moving here?

Comment: The reason I started with a macro is that it expands to different types on different build environment. So it's a legacy choice and I still hope to fix the macro.

Comment: A move constructor cannot be added because on some environments MyClass would be a library class which cannot be modified.

Comment: Anyway overloaded factory function is not an option because I still have to pass the "hardcoded" arguments - the "this" pointer and its cv-qualifier. The solution is supposed to fill them in automatically if omitted. The initial question is how to fix the macro, so your answer is unrelated.

Comment: @user3348108 Your question, as it is, is an example of [the XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). You have a solution you want us to help you with, but we don't actually know the problem the solution is attempting to solve. There may be other ways of solving the problem, but we can't really tell since the question doesn't tell us the *actual* problem.

Comment: The question is very clear: how to make the macro expand in the expected way.

Comment: @user3348108, why do you keep getting distracted by false claims about speed and about the stack? You say *"And that is why I am trying to place them on stack"*, however a good compiler will directly construct your item in place, without any moving and without any copying

Answer (score 0):

If constructors of `MyClass` are not `explicit` nor conflicting with an initializer_list constructor, you may use the following which doesn't call move/copy constructor:

```
MyClass make_MyClass() { return {hardcoded_arg}; }

template <typename T>
MyClass make_MyClass(T&& arg) { return {hardcoded_arg, std::forward<T>(arg)}; }

template <typename T1, typename T2>
MyClass make_MyClass(T1&& arg1, T2&& arg2)
{
    return {std::forward<T1>(arg1), std::forward<T2>(arg2)};
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3c7711d4df4a270a)

Comment: Thank you for the answer but it is unrelated to my question. I'm asking how to fix the macro. If the situation would be that trivial I would not as for help. Your solution can't handle the default argument values which are the 'this' pointer and boolean representing its cv-qualifier.

Comment: Which `this` pointer do you talk about ? I saw nothing related to that in your Question (to allow to update my answer accordantly if possible).